# usb gps and gpsd vs. ntpd shared memory driver

Tags: gpsd, ntpd

I configured ntpd on my system like so:

```
~$ cat /etc/ntp.conf
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift    
logfile /var/log/ntp.log
statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable    

server 0.de.pool.ntp.org                                                                                                                                                                         
server 1.de.pool.ntp.org                                                                                                                                                                         
server 2.de.pool.ntp.org                                                                                                                                                                         
server 3.de.pool.ntp.org                                                                                                                                                                         

restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

server 127.127.8.0 mode 2     # standard time string with 9600, 7E2

# gpsd
server 127.127.28.0
fudge 127.127.28.0 refid GPSa
server 127.127.28.1
fudge 127.127.28.1 refid GPSp
```

ntpq tells me that ntpd gets the time from gps as desired:

```
~$ ntpq -c peers
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
-ns2.bvc-cloud.d 192.53.103.104   2 u   64   64  177   14.959  155.440 113.066
+mail.danzuck.eu 192.53.103.104   2 u    -   64  377   10.176  -54.295 129.782
-ntp01.cc-netzwe 240.67.35.84     3 u   65   64  177   13.674   63.774  64.264
-server2.as2.ch  131.188.3.223    2 u   59   64  177   14.758   87.117  67.824
*GENERIC(0)      .DCFa.           0 l    2   64    3    0.000  -65.610   0.733
+SHM(0)          .GPSa.           0 l  323   64  140    0.000  -18.353  12.003
 SHM(1)          .GPSp.           0 l    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

So obivously gpsd must be running. However ntpd does not get the pps signal. Is this to be expected for an USB GPS? That is: should I remove the configuration for GPSp? If not so: how can I find out why it fails?

Comment: You really do not give much information. Does your kernel support PPS? What do the gpsd/ntp logs say? When you ran gpsd with debuggging turned on did you see anything about the PPS signal? It does not look like your GPS is working that well: last is 323 and reach is 140. FYI: this is not really a stackoverflow question. You should follow this guide: http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/GPS-time.html

Answer (score -1):

Change line:

fudge 127.127.28.1 refid GPSp

to

fudge 127.127.28.1 refid GPSp prefer

That should fix it.